# HTML RowSpan Formatting Issue

Tags: html, html-table

Ok, so I am creating a table that is supposed to look like this:

[image: Desired Result]

I have the table element portion of my HTML code below:

```html
<table class="schedule">
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tue</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thu</th>
    <th>Fri</th>
    <th>Sat</th>
    <th>Sun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>6:00 PM</th>
    <td colspan="7">National News</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>6:30 PM</th>
    <td colspan="7">World News</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>7:00 PM</th>
    <td rowspan="2">Opera Fest</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Radio U</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Science Week</td>
    <td rowspan="2">The Living World</td>
    <td>Word Play</td>
    <td>Agri-Week</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Folk Fest</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>7:30 PM
      <th>
        <td>Brain Stew</td>
        <td>Bismarck Forum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But when I open the HTML file in any browser I get this table instead:

[image: Result I Get]

Answer (score 1):

You make a small mistake at

```
<th>7:30 PM<th>
```

That missing closed tag makes HTML think you have 2 `th` (not only 1 as you expected)

The fix could be making the 2nd `th` to be a closed tag

```
<th>7:30 PM</th>
```

Full HTML

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="schedule">
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>6:00 PM</th>
            <td colspan="7">National News</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>6:30 PM</th>
            <td colspan="7">World News</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>7:00 PM</th>
            <td rowspan="2">Opera Fest</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Radio U</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Science Week</td>
            <td rowspan="2">The Living World</td>
            <td>Word Play</td>
            <td>Agri-Week</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Folk Fest</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>7:30 PM</th>
            <td>Brain Stew</td>
            <td>Bismarck Forum</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```